# How to understand a lot of bug messages exactly after the start?

Tags: bug-reporting, debugging

I receive a lot of annoying "system program problem detected" exactly after the start of my ubuntu (usually 5-6). And I can't understand what is it.

Window is closing and nothing happens when I click on "Report problem...". How can I understand the reason of these bug messages on the start? What's going wrong?

[image]

**UPDATED**

These lines may be possible errors, isn't it?

```
serge@loungepc:~$ dmesg | grep exception
[    0.132125] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[    0.132129] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
```

Comment: Look at results of `dmesg` and in the file `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @Xen2050 I saw it but not found anything special

Comment: Click "Report problem..." and wait some time while the details of the problem are being retrieved. Then you will see an explanation of the crash .

Comment: @Jos I don't see anything

Comment: Hey everyone I updated the question